# Como fazer pra não fazer nada quando clicar na mesma div#box1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu quero quando clicar na div id box1 2vezes ou mais não fazer nada usando Jquery e/ou javascript

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var exe=false;
   var nuns=0;
   $('div#box1').on("click", function(){
    if(nuns==0){
     if(exe!=false){ exe.hide('fast');  }
     exe = $(this).children('#submenu');
     $(this).children('#submenu').slideToggle('fast');
     nuns=1;
    }else{
     exe.hide('fast');
     exe = $(this).children('#submenu');
     $(this).children('#submenu').slideToggle('fast');
     nuns=0;
    }
   });
  });
```

```css
div#box1{
  border: 1px solid rgba(155,243,253,0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* background: rgba(246,185,181,0.23); */
  background: rgba(25, 136, 196, 0.28) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  padding: 5px 1px 1px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
 }
 div#box1 p{ font-size:12pt; padding: 1px; }
 div#box1 h2 { border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 5px; padding: 1px 0px 1px 12px; 
  background: rgba(100,100,100,.1);
 }
 img#img_del {position: relative;top: -45px;left: -12px; }
 #submenu { display: none; }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
 </script>
 <style type="text/css">
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="text-left" id="box1">
 <div id="box2"> 
  <a onclick="">
   <h2>oi</h2>
  </a>
  <a href="#4321">
   <img id="img_del" align="right" src="/img/close.jpg">
  </a>
 </div>
 <div id="submenu">
  <h3><p>Pontos:500</p></h3>
  <h3><p>undefined</p></h3>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="text-left" id="box1">
 <div id="box2"> 
  <a onclick="">
   <h2>oi</h2>
  </a>
  <a href="#4321">
   <img id="img_del" align="right" src="/img/close.jpg">
  </a>
 </div>
 <div id="submenu">
  <h3><p>Pontos:500</p></h3>
  <h3><p>undefined</p></h3>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="text-left" id="box1">
 <div id="box2"> 
  <a onclick="">
   <h2>oi</h2>
  </a>
  <a href="#4321">
   <img id="img_del" align="right" src="/img/close.jpg">
  </a>
 </div>
 <div id="submenu">
  <h3><p>Pontos:500</p></h3>
  <h3><p>undefined</p></h3>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="text-left" id="box1">
 <div id="box2"> 
  <a onclick="">
   <h2>oi</h2>
  </a>
  <a href="#4321">
   <img id="img_del" align="right" src="/img/close.jpg">
  </a>
 </div>
 <div id="submenu">
  <h3><p>Pontos:500</p></h3>
  <h3><p>undefined</p></h3>
 </div>
</div>
<body>
<html>
```

Comment: Eu me espressei mal. O certo é: -Sempre que clicar no submenu não é pra disparar o evento do jquery.

Comment: alguem ajuda ae

Answer (score 1):

O seu código necessita de algumas correcções

1. O uso de **id** nao pos de duplicado, deve user o atributo **class**:
2. A animação nao esta perfeita, deve fechar e abrir o submenu devidamente,
   deve usar: `$(this).children('#submenu').animate({"margin-top":"0px"});`

Aqui vai o código com a minha solução

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            var exe=false;
            var nuns=0;
            $('.box1').on("click", function(){
                if(nuns==0){
                    if(exe!=false){ exe.hide('fast');  }
                    exe = $(this).children('#submenu');
                    $(this).children('#submenu').slideToggle('fast');
                    nuns=1;
                }else{
                //Commente este trecho do **else** para não haver repetição caso seja este o objectivo.
                exe.hide('fast');
                exe = $(this).children('#submenu');
                $(this).children('#submenu').animate({"margin-top":"0px"});
                nuns=0;
            }
        });
     });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
     .box1{
     border: 1px solid rgba(155,243,253,0.5);
     border-radius: 5px;
     /* background: rgba(246,185,181,0.23); */
     background: rgba(25, 136, 196, 0.28) none repeat scroll 0 0;
     padding: 5px 1px 1px 5px;
     margin: 5px;
     }
     .box1 p{ font-size:12pt; padding: 1px; }
     .box1 h2 { border: 1px solid black;    border-radius: 5px; padding: 1px 0px 1px 12px; 
     background: rgba(100,100,100,.1);
     }
     img#img_del {position: relative;top: -45px;left: -12px; }
     #submenu { display: none; }
  </style>


</head>
   <body>
      <div class="box1">
         <div id="box2">
            <a onclick="">
               <h2>oi</h2>
            </a>
            <a href="#4321">
            <img id="img_del" align="right" src="/img/close.jpg">
            </a>
         </div>
         <div id="submenu">
            <h3>
               <p>Pontos:500</p>
            </h3>
            <h3>
               <p>undefined</p>
            </h3>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <div id="box2">
            <a onclick="">
               <h2>oi</h2>
            </a>
            <a href="#4321">
            <img id="img_del" align="right" src="/img/close.jpg">
            </a>
         </div>
         <div id="submenu">
            <h3>
               <p>Pontos:500</p>
            </h3>
            <h3>
               <p>undefined</p>
            </h3>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <div id="box2">
            <a onclick="">
               <h2>oi</h2>
            </a>
            <a href="#4321">
            <img id="img_del" align="right" src="/img/close.jpg">
            </a>
         </div>
         <div id="submenu">
            <h3>
               <p>Pontos:500</p>
            </h3>
            <h3>
               <p>undefined</p>
            </h3>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```